# Exploiting a referer open redirect

Tags: web-application

I wanted to know if it is possible to exploit the fact that in my webapp the Referer header of a request is being reflected in the response.

For example:

```
GET /endpoint1 HTTP/2
Host: mysite.com
Cookie: session=3276372
Referer: evil.com
```

The response will be

```
HTTP/2 302 Found
Location: evil.com
```

I don't filter the quotes and tags <> in the header.

It is an Open Redirect vulnerability, but it seems to be unexploitable.

Answer (score 1):

Open redirect vulnerabilities are usually only exploited when it can be chained with another vulnerability, for example in a login flow that uses oAuth, so that depends on the other features of your application. Exploiting XSS is rare and usually not possible due to the way browsers encode the header for you. There are some old examples where XSS was possible in Internet Explorer, but for modern browsers this is not an issue.